# Powershell run exe on remote computer using a UNC path t

Tags: powershell, exe

From PC A I'm trying to run this script. It should on PC B run a Exe. The Exe it will run resides on PC C. These are windows 7 OS PCs PC C are server 2008\2012

```
 $text ='Start-process -FilePath "\\<serverpath>\App.exe" "`-f switch`.switch"'
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PCname -Scriptblock { param ($text)
 $text | Invoke-Expression
 }
```

The command in $text runs from the powershell console on the remote PC just correctly. 
Running the entire script gives:
This command cannot be executed due to the error: Access is denied.

Doing some research I believe I'm running into the "[double hop issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-6)"

Brief description.

You have computer A, B, and C. You want to run a script from A, that has B run a script\process on C. Your credentials won't pass from B to C.

Due to requirements I think using the method of

```
$cred = Get-Credential Contoso\Administrator
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerB -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    hostname
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerC -Credential $Using:cred -ScriptBlock {hostname}
}
```

As explained in the link. One issue I think I'm running into is I want the process to run on PC B its only the exe that resides on PC C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote call from PC-A to PB-B and PC-B needs to run a .exe on PC-C.

Invoke-Command requires you be admin on whatever target you are trying to hit and that is only for that target.

Are you saying you tried that last block of code and it failed?

Because, if all remoting is configured properly, it should work this way.

```
$PC_A = 'ws01'
$PC_B = 'iis01'
$cred = Get-Credential "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME"

"Running from $env:COMPUTERNAME"
"Targetng $PC_A"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PC_A -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
    "Targeting $Using:PC_B from $Using:PC_A via remote source"
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Using:PC_B -Credential $Using:cred -ScriptBlock {"PC_B name is $env:COMPUTERNAME"
        notepad.exe
        Get-Process -Name notepad
    }
}

# Results

Running from DC01
Targetng ws01
Targeting iis01 from ws01 via remote source
PC_B name is IIS01

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName  PSComputerName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------  --------------
    172      10     2184       9424 ...29     0.02   3520 notepad      ws01
```

You should also look at using PSDrive to the .exe on the second hop instead of the extra remote effort and running the .exe as if it was on the first hop.

Comment: Remote call from PC-A to PB-B and PC-B needs to run a .exe on PC-C. Close....Remote call from PC-A to PB-B and PC-B needs to run a .exe Located on PC-C.

Comment: I get that and that is what I am showing in the sample. $env:computername (your PC-A) is the initial source to target PC-A (your PC-B), PC-A (your PC-B) is the source for PC-B ( your PC-C), executing notepad on PC-B (your PC-A), and that is a non-interactive thing. You can only run an app on any remote host in your own context, not the context of any user on a remote host. PS does not allow this, as it is a security boundary. If you want to run that app in the remote users context, the you have to use a 3rdP tool like psexec from sysinternals.

Comment: "You can only run an app on any remote host in your own context" I just need to face facts - I can't do what I want in pure PS.  I have a alternate way of doing what I want through scheduling a Altiris job.